# Why and how almost periodic series constitute the algebra of observable of integrable systems?

Tags: classical-mechanics, complex-systems, integrable-systems, integrals-of-motion

In the introduction of his book [*Noncommutative Geometry,*](http://www.alainconnes.org/en/downloads.php) p. 42,  Connes explains that when a classical dynamical system has enough constants of motions, the motion of the system is [almost periodic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_periodic_function), and the algebra of observables is the algebra of almost periodic series

$$q(t) = \sum q_{n_1 \dots n_k} \, \exp( 2 \pi i \left\langle n, \nu \right\rangle t),$$

where $n_i$ are integers and $\nu_i$ "fundamental frequencies" (and $\left\langle n, \nu \right\rangle = \sum n_i \nu_i$).

From what does this come from?

I believe that "enough constants of motion" means that the system is somehow integrable, and perhaps the Arnold-Liouville theorem can help provide an answer to this question, but I am not familiar with this domain, and I hope someone will know better what Cones means.